# Having a model Concern when the models don't have standardised methods in them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Concern that expects all models using it to have a `.person` function.

The models using it are:
`Bike` `House` `Person` `Garden`

All of these belong to `Person` with the exception of `Person` itself and my concern calls `self.person` in order to fetch the `Person` object.

I don't really want to duplicate this code just for `Person` so I'm wondering what the best solution could be?

Here's why I need it

```
# concern.rb
def unauthorised_items?
  self.person.authorised? # self.person isn't found when calling from a Person instance
end
```

Whats the best way to keep this concern belonging to `Person`. I'm happy to make adjustments if I need to.

In reality it's a much larger method, hence why I don't want to repeat it elsewhere just so I can switch `self.person.authorised?` with `self.authorised?`

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about adding a `person` method to Person that returns self? That might get you what you want (although you could argue it's a bit odd).

Comment: That is a little bit odd. But it would definitely work. Can you think of any problems this might cause? and do you think it would be considered as hacky?

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas: In the long term, you might come back to it and ask, "Why do I need a person method on Person?" You could argue that maybe this question indicates a code smell i.e. maybe there's a better way to design what you're trying to accomplish. You could also say that if you need to do something special for Person, is this really a concern for Person? Just throwing out my immediate thoughts - I could be totally wrong here.

Comment: Those are very good points, I totally agree with you. I do like the simple implementation though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the record for its type first:

```
def authorised_items?
  record = is_a?(Person) ? self : self.person
  record.authorised?
end
```

Comment: Ok, so that would stop me from calling it from the context of Person? Maybe I asked the question incorrectly.. but I would like to be able to call from Person and it'll still work